# Symfony 3.0 Neither the property "category" nor one of the methods "getCategory()" etc ERROR in JOBEET

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

Trying to write my first app on Symfony 2 withs this manual http://www.ens.ro/2012/03/27/symfony2-jobeet-day-3-the-data-model/
All my code like in manual but with my namespaces and i got

> Neither the property "category" nor one of the methods
>   "getCategory()", "category()", "isCategory()", "hasCategory()",
>   "__get()" exist and have public access in class
>   "JobeetBundle\Entity\Job".

I think this error generated in Form/JobType.php

```
class JobType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type')
            ->add('company')
            ->add('logo')
            ->add('url')
            ->add('position')
            ->add('location')
            ->add('description')
            ->add('how_to_apply')
            ->add('token')
            ->add('is_public')
            ->add('is_activated')
            ->add('email')
            ->add('expires_at', DateType::Class)
            ->add('created_at',DateType::Class)
            ->add('updated_at',DateType::Class)
            ->add('category') ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'JobeetBundle\Entity\Job'
        ));
    }
}
```

But i haven't object like category in Entity\Job 
it should be reference from Entity\Category but still not working.. 
Please help. And Some my code below:
Entity/CAtegory.php:

```
   ?php

namespace JobeetBundle\Entity;

/**
 * Category
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @var integer
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $jobs;

/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $category_affiliates;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->jobs = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->category_affiliates = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Category
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Add job
 *
 * @param \JobeetBundle\Entity\Job $job
 *
 * @return Category
 */
public function addJob(\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job $job)
{
    $this->jobs[] = $job;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove job
 *
 * @param \JobeetBundle\Entity\Job $job
 */
public function removeJob(\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job $job)
{
    $this->jobs->removeElement($job);
}

/**
 * Get jobs
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getJobs()
{
    return $this->jobs;
}

/**
 * Add categoryAffiliate
 *
 * @param \JobeetBundle\Entity\CategoryAffiliate $categoryAffiliate
 *
 * @return Category
 */
public function addCategoryAffiliate(\JobeetBundle\Entity\CategoryAffiliate $categoryAffiliate)
{
    $this->category_affiliates[] = $categoryAffiliate;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove categoryAffiliate
 *
 * @param \JobeetBundle\Entity\CategoryAffiliate $categoryAffiliate
 */
public function removeCategoryAffiliate(\JobeetBundle\Entity\CategoryAffiliate $categoryAffiliate)
{
    $this->category_affiliates->removeElement($categoryAffiliate);
}

/**
 * Get categoryAffiliates
 *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getCategoryAffiliates()
    {
        return $this->category_affiliates;
    }
    public function __toString()
   {
    return $this->getName();
   }
}
```

Entity/Job.php

```
    <?php

namespace JobeetBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Job
 */
class Job
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $type;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $company;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $logo;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $position;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $howToApply;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $token;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $isPublic;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $isActivated;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $expiresAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $categoryId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param string $type
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setType($type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Set company
     *
     * @param string $company
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setCompany($company)
    {
        $this->company = $company;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get company
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCompany()
    {
        return $this->company;
    }

    /**
     * Set logo
     *
     * @param string $logo
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setLogo($logo)
    {
        $this->logo = $logo;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get logo
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLogo()
    {
        return $this->logo;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set position
     *
     * @param string $position
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setPosition($position)
    {
        $this->position = $position;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get position
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPosition()
    {
        return $this->position;
    }

    /**
     * Set location
     *
     * @param string $location
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setLocation($location)
    {
        $this->location = $location;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get location
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    /**
     * Set description
     *
     * @param string $description
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set howToApply
     *
     * @param string $howToApply
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setHowToApply($howToApply)
    {
        $this->howToApply = $howToApply;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get howToApply
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getHowToApply()
    {
        return $this->howToApply;
    }

    /**
     * Set token
     *
     * @param string $token
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setToken($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get token
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToken()
    {
        return $this->token;
    }

    /**
     * Set isPublic
     *
     * @param boolean $isPublic
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setIsPublic($isPublic)
    {
        $this->isPublic = $isPublic;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isPublic
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsPublic()
    {
        return $this->isPublic;
    }

    /**
     * Set isActivated
     *
     * @param boolean $isActivated
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setIsActivated($isActivated)
    {
        $this->isActivated = $isActivated;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get isActivated
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function getIsActivated()
    {
        return $this->isActivated;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set expiresAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $expiresAt
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setExpiresAt($expiresAt)
    {
        $this->expiresAt = $expiresAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get expiresAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getExpiresAt()
    {
        return $this->expiresAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set categoryId
     *
     * @param integer $categoryId
     *
     * @return Job
     */
    public function setCategoryId($categoryId)
    {
        $this->categoryId = $categoryId;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categoryId
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getCategoryId()
    {
        return $this->categoryId;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

Well i can show other code if u need it for make this app come true ::C:C:C Please help. Thx

Comment: Remove the `->add('category')` or replace it by the correct name, i.e. `->add('categoryId')`

Comment: but i'm need chose CATEGORY reference by category_id in my form..

Comment: So you need to define an association Job->Category, see [Association mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) and [Working with associations](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html), you surely need a one-to-one. Then you'll have the method `getCategory()` and it will work.

Comment: ty, bro, but i fix the issue with another

Comment: Just recreate entity and it work :)